# select2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this html

```
 <div class="input-box">
        <select id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select" name="billing[country_id]" title="Country">
            <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select id="billing:region_id" class="validate-select" name="billing[region_id]" title="State">
            <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#billing\\:country_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Country"
    });

    jQuery("#billing\\:region_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select State"
    });

    jQuery("#billing\\:country_id").change(function(){
        jQuery("#billing\\:region_id").select2('destroy'); 

        jQuery("#billing\\:region_id").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a State"
        });
    });
</script>
```

but when I try to change the country dropdown I have this error:

***TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function***

jQuery("#billing\:region_id").select2('destroy');

Comment: Not included select2.js ?

Comment: is included, the country select is work okay, but when there exist state dropdown I see this error

Comment: make sure you import select2.js before the code. and remove `\\ ` from `#billing\\:region_id & #billing\\:country_id`

Comment: if I remove this will not work, the ID will can't be selected

Comment: Use jquery function first to encapsulate your whole code. e.g `$(function(){//your remaining code write here.})` and let me know the status.

Comment: can you show me how please?

Comment: could it be cause you are doing
jQuery("#billing\\:region_id").select2('destroy');  and destroying the select2 dropdown?

Comment: this dropdowns are related, so some countries have state others no

Comment: there it seems to be the problem in that destroy

Comment: Any public url where we can see you code?

Comment: no is on my local server

Comment: So, select2 works before doing anything with it? It's styled like in the jsfiddle shown and the placeholder is visible? And what happens if you disable the line with the destroy? Did you double check there's no typo's and no other code which could disable select2. What version of jquery and version of select2? Did you try a newer or older version of select2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any error except that your whole function should be encapsulated inside jquery.To show demo, i just added 3 options.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#billing\\:country_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Country"
    });

    $("#billing\\:region_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select State"
    });

    $("#billing\\:country_id").change(function(){
        $("#billing\\:region_id").select2('destroy'); 

        $("#billing\\:region_id").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a State"
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<div class="input-box">
    <select id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select" name="billing[country_id]" title="Country">
        <option value=""> </option>
  
  <option value="1">option 1 </option>
  <option value="2">option 2 </option>
  <option value="3">option 3 </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
    <select id="billing:region_id" class="validate-select" name="billing[region_id]" title="State">
        <option value=""> </option>
  <option value="1">option 1 </option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/36v5ms5c/1/).

Comment: You're not using `:` in the id's. Use them to rule out it's not the selector or the css escaping causing the error... so I tested it (using the onload, not the $.ready): https://jsfiddle.net/36v5ms5c/1/